# Как отцентрировать карту в зависимости от маркеров?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, openlayers

Добавляю на карту много маркеров — как отцентрировать карту в зависимости от положения маркеров?

Вот так вот я разворачиваю карту в `map-canvas`:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map-canvas');
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lngJS,latJS).transform(), 12);
markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers('Markers' );
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Вот так вот создаю маркеры когда нужно:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( y ,x ).transform( new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), map.getProjectionObject());
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(34, 41);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('../storage/marker/'+imgMarker,size);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat,icon));
```

Что бы вы лучше меня понимали, у меня есть написанные скрипты того, что я хочу на 
Google Maps:

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
// places массив координат
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) 
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i][0], places[i][1]);
    latlngbounds.extend(myLatLng);
}
map.map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.map.fitBounds(latlngbounds));   
if(map.getZoom()>18)
{
 map.setZoom(17);
}
else if(map.getZoom()<4&&statusresize==2)
{
 map.setZoom(10);
}
```

Так же есть скрипт для Яндекс.Карты:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
if(myCollection.getLength()>0)
{
    var centerAndZoom = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
          myCollection.getBounds(),
          myMap.container.getSize(),
          myMap.options.get('projection')
    );
    myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds()); 
    if(myMap.getZoom()>18)
    {
       myMap.setZoom(17);
    }
    else if(myMap.getZoom()==0&&statusresize==2)
    {
       myMap.setZoom(10);
    }
}
});
```

В общем, как правильно отцентрировать карту в зависимости от положения маркеров?

Comment: [похожий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/x5R63/)

Answer (score 1):

создается переменная

```
var bounds;
```

При инициализации карты помещаем в переменную экземпляр OpenLayers.Bounds

```
bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
```

Когда заполняем маркеры так же и набиваем bounds

```
bounds.extend(lonLat);
```

И когда нам нужно отцентрировать карту делаем следующее:

```
var myOpenZoom = map.getZoomForExtent(bounds);
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenterLonLat(),myOpenZoom);
```